useeffect in nextjs 14 firing twice at page load
I have a client component in next js which uses useeffect to call an api, however its is calling twice at page load the api, i dont know why. here is the client component:
'use client';

import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useInView } from 'react-intersection-observer';

import { CaretSortIcon, CheckIcon } from '@radix-ui/react-icons';
import { cn } from '@/app/lib/utils';
import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button';
import {
  Command,
  CommandEmpty,
  CommandGroup,
  CommandInput,
  CommandItem,
  CommandList,
} from '@/components/ui/command';
import {
  Popover,
  PopoverContent,
  PopoverTrigger,
} from '@/components/ui/popover';
import { usePathname, useRouter, useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';
import { useDebouncedCallback } from 'use-debounce';

let offset = 0;

export function ComboboxDemo({ services }: { services: string[] }) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const initialQuery = searchParams.get('query_service') || '';
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(initialQuery);

  const { replace } = useRouter();
  const pathname = usePathname();

  const { ref, inView } = useInView();
  const [data, setData] = useState<string[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inView) {
      const fetchService = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(
          `/dashboard/inventory/api/services?offset=${offset}`,
        );
        const result = await response.json();
        return result;
      };
      fetchService().then((res) => {
        setData([...data, ...res]);
      });
    }
    console.log('i fire once');
  }, [inView, data]);

and here is the api endpoint:
import { db } from '@/drizzle/db';
import { evergreen } from '@/drizzle/schema';
import { ilike, sql } from 'drizzle-orm';
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

const limit = 100;

export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {
  const { searchParams } = new URL(req.url);
  const offset = searchParams.get('offset') || 0;

  const dataPromise = db
    .selectDistinct({
      it_service: evergreen.it_service,
    })
    .from(evergreen)
    .offset(sql.placeholder('offset'))
    .limit(limit)
    .prepare('distinct_it');

  const data = await dataPromise.execute({ offset: offset });
  console.log(data);

  const services = data.map((item) => item.it_service);

  return NextResponse.json(services, { status: 200 });
}

P.S: I am not in Strict Mode.
Another thing to note is that the API endoint is a route handler, not a server action.

Does this answer your question? Why useEffect running twice and how to handle it well in React?

i am not in strict mode

another thing to note is that the API endpoint is a route handler, not a server action. Thanks

Interestingly enough, I just came across this post regarding the useState hook being called twice in a Next.js app and it turns out the Next.js enables the React StrictMode by default (as it should be the default everywhere). If this is the case here as well then you can turn it off if you wanted, but I don't recommend that at all, StrictMode doesn't run in production builds anyway, so it's only there to help surface logical bugs/issues in your code in non-production builds.

It would seem you have added a dependency to the useEffect hook that the callback updates. This will trigger the effect to run again.
useEffect(() => {
  if (inView) {
    const fetchService = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        `/dashboard/inventory/api/services?offset=${offset}`,
      );
      const result = await response.json();
      return result;
    };
    fetchService().then((res) => {
      setData([...data, ...res]); // <-- updates data state
    });
  }
  console.log('i fire once');
}, [inView, data]); // <-- data state is dependency

Remove data as an external dependency by using a functional state update, i.e. using an updater function that is passed the current state value in order to compute and return the next state value.
Example:
useEffect(() => {
  if (inView) {
    const fetchService = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        `/dashboard/inventory/api/services?offset=${offset}`,
      );
      const result = await response.json();
      setData(data => [...data, ...result]);
      // or setData(data => data.concat(...result));
    };

    fetchService();
  }
}, [inView]);


For anyone reading this, its totally fine to for useEffect to fire twice on development environment, but once in production. Reference here
If you feel confused, make sure you read the react docs and test it out like I did to confirm
